# Cloudfront 403 bypass

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

to give some context I am for the first time trying to participate in a BugBounty program and I found out which cloudfront URL is serving content to a website and the content being served is in json format.

- Each time I try to access the information through the url of the website I get the next message:
  {"error":"You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."}
- If I try to access the Cloudfront url(xxxxxxx.cloudfront.net) I get:
  403 ERROR
  The request could not be satisfied.
  Bad request. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
  If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
  Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront) and a request id

I would like to know if somebody know a good article that explains how to bypass those 403 or 401 messages and obtain the JSON output

Thank you very much for all the information provided in advance.